# Does Xamarin remove/exclude the simulator architecture of the native library when building for Appstore / Device build?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.ios-binding

I'm creating a Xamarin iOS binding library and my plan was to publish it to NuGet. However, I just realized that the native library currently has all architectures (simulator and device):

```
libMySDKSDK.a (for architecture i386):  current ar archive
libMySDKSDK.a (for architecture armv7): current ar archive
libMySDKSDK.a (for architecture x86_64):current ar archive
libMySDKSDK.a (for architecture arm64): current ar archive
```

Will this be a problem for users when they are submitting to the AppStore? I believe Apple will reject the app if it has the simulator slices in there.

Does Xamarin automatically take care of this or does it need to be explicitly handled?

Thanks

Comment: When *statically* linking a `FAT` library, only the build/app architecture(s) are used in the build/archive process which can only be armv7 and/or arm64 thus the i386/x86_64 ABIs are not included. Embedded frameworks **are** different, it is up to the developer to strip the unneeded ABIs from any 3rd-party or their own frameworks that they are including as the Framework itself is included as a whole.